# bootstrap tagsinput source not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to bind `tagsinput` with source option but it is not working. I am not understanding what I am missing there. Its a small code which I took from their official site http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Nice-Tags-Manager-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Tags-Input/examples/. Also there is no error on console. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4jy9d4/30/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#aa').tagsinput({
    source:['ams','bms','lite']
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but I feel that I must share my experience. I've tried **A LOT** of these third-party javascript `tagging systems` (including yours). Some didn't workedl; some did but some functionality was missing, etc. The solution that I've found to work best is [selectize.js](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/). It has most of the required functionality, here is some of it:

- Add and remove items in any order without touching your mouse.
- You can choose whether the user can create new tags or use only the ones you've provided for them
- You can limit the count to your tags
- It has a nice interface
- It is fairly simple to use

I know this doesn't answer your question but I just feel obliged to tell you given the fact that I've wasted so much time searching for that kind of thing.